# Pinescript variable doesn't change its value

Tags: pine-script-v5

To make it simple, I'll give another piece of code.

```
currentRSI = ta.rsi(close,14)
var tradeExists = 0
if (currentRSI > 50 and tradeExists == 0)
    tradeExists := 1
    alert("Long trade")
```

In my case, if `currentRSI` crosses over 50, so it gets to 51, AND in the same candle of the timeframe it gets to 49.5, the `tradeExists` value will remain 0 but the alert has been sent. How could I fix to detect that and close the trade, any idea if I can do this?

I want to specify that I also tried using `varip tradeExists = 0` but the variable still gets rollback at the close of the candle.

Answer (score 1):

I just had that problem and I fixed it: use
the `barstate.isconfirmed` in your conditions, it's the only way to change a var in pinescript.

```
if (barstate.isconfirmed and first_time_signal == false)
    if nT3Average >= ok_to_buy and nT3Average_2 <= oversold 
        last_signal := 1
        label.new(bar_index,close,'Long',color=color.rgb(49, 161, 64),style = label.style_label_up,xloc=xloc.bar_index,yloc=yloc.belowbar)
        first_time_signal := true

    if nT3Average <= ok_to_sell and nT3Average_2 >= overbought 
        last_signal := -1
        label.new(bar_index,close,'Short',color=color.rgb(175, 55, 95),style = label.style_label_down,xloc=xloc.bar_index,yloc=yloc.abovebar,textcolor=color.rgb(10,10,10))
        first_time_signal := true
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).